# Calling Angular Component Instance Method in Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have a method that's part of a custom component that I have created in Angular:

```
public editSite(site: siteModel): void {
    this.currentState = pageState.EditSite;
    this.editSiteService.siteId = site.guid;
}
```

I want to create a test that will execute this function from within my Jasmine test and then verify that both `this.currentState` and `this.editSiteService.siteId` have been set to their expected values.

Here is what I currently have in my test:

```
describe('method: editSite()', () => {
    it('should execute and set variables accordingly', () => {
        // Arrange - Act
        const editSiteSpy = spyOn(component, 'editSite').and.callThrough();
        // Assert
        expect(editSiteSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I'm setting up component and fixture as normal:

```
let component: SiteComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SiteComponet>;

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SiteComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

When the test runs however:

> SiteComponent method: editSite() should execute and set variables accordingly FAILED

Any clues as to why this may be happening? Are there better ways of testing the functionality I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: You aren't calling editSite() anywhere. You are simply creating a spy for it, and then asserting that you expected it to have been called.

Comment: @Pytth After doing `ng -v` it looks like 5.1.2

Comment: @Pytth I actually missed a part of my code there. I've updated it

Comment: Hey man, I still don't think you are doing what you expect. Here, you are saying that you want to create a spy for a method, and that you want that method to not only be called, but when it is called, to actually delegate to the real functionality.

Comment: @Pytth So there's a better way to achieve this, or am I just doing/thinking about this in the wrong way? :sweat-smile:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164296/discussion-between-user-5842-and-pytth).